# wget equivalent on cocoa

Tags: cocoa, http, request, wget

I want to send an http request from cocoa app which would do the same thing of 
wget [http://192.168.1.22:8000/toto/tata/0.1/titi/i386].

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look at [`NSURLDownload`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, you should do something similar to:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.22:8000/toto/tata/0.1/titi/i386"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithUrl:url];
NSURLDownload *download = [[NSURLDownload] alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[download setDestination:@"path" allowOverwrite:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the NSURLConnection class, or maybe NSURLDownload